# used to AND sometimes

Tags: collocations

This is from Animal Farm:

> "Jones *used sometimes to* mix some of it in our mash," said one of the hens.

*Used to* means that something happened continuously or frequently during a period in the past.
It confuses me when used together with *sometimes*. There is a conflict in meaning, isn't it?

Comment: _Used to_ means that he had a habit of doing so, but _sometimes_ shows that it wasn't a regular habit.

Comment: The hens got the mash every day, but sometimes Jones used to mix milk with it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I looked up the word [habit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habit#Noun), it shows me theses: _1. An action performed on a regular basis. 2. An action performed repeatedly and automatically, usually without awareness. _

Comment: @preachers - despite what Wikipedia says, a habit can be occasional. Example: "When not in class, it was my occasional habit to go for long walks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Used to” refers to a general action that continuously happened during a period in the past, usually something semi-regular (as t continuous actions tend to be regular) but not necessarily. That being said, it can be modified for further descriptiveness and clarity.

> I used to laugh **far more** than I do now.
>
> We used to go to the farm **every week**, but now we hardly ever visit.
>
> My dad used to cook **sometimes**, but now it’s mostly just me.

In the excerpt, the form has simply been shifted to the more uncommon “used sometimes to [verb]” instead of “used to [verb] sometimes.” You can see how different phrases can be used to describe the frequency, regularity, and timing of the verb phrase “used to ___” The phrase “used to” does not only refer to habitual actions or behaviors; it simply refers to something that went on continuously at some point in the past.

> I used to dance, ***but** now I don’t.*
>
> I used to dance competitively, ***but** now I dance just for fun.*
>
> I used to dance once a week, ***but** now I don’t dance at all*.
>
> I used to dance whenever I felt like it, ***but** now I have to be on a schedule.*

All of those are acceptable sentences. I have italicized the latter half of each sentence and bolded “but” to illustrate some contrasting clauses that might help you understand how “used to” is being modified. As you can see, “used to dance” remains the same in each sentence, but it is not necessarily a habitual or regular practice.

It might be helpful to think of the original sentence as saying that it was Jones’ regular *habit* to only *sometimes* mix it in.